# SQL ignore null user input in WHERE clauses

Tags: java, html, sql, select, servlets

[userInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39n8p.png)

I am trying to figure this out for two days but all the answers are too advanced. I need a simple, easy solution, please.

I want to make a book search feature using HTML forms and POST requests to a jetty servlet. The user can either search using the book's name, author name or price range. Depending on the user input, I will generate the SQL query. My query looks like this: -

*(title, author and minPrice, maxPrice are user input variables.)*

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE Title LIKE '%title%' 
   OR Author LIKE '%author%' 
   OR Price BETWEEN minPrice AND maxPrice;
```

If the user puts a price range, it works perfectly. But if they do not, the query ends up being:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE Title LIKE '%%' 
   OR Author LIKE '%%' 
   OR Price BETWEEN  AND;
```

and this returns nothing.

What is the best way to go about it?

Java code:

```
query = "SELECT * 
         FROM books 
         WHERE Title LIKE '%" + request.getParameter("title") + "%' 
            OR Author LIKE '%" + request.getParameter("author") + "%' 
            OR Price BETWEEN " + request.getParameter("minPrice") + 
                      " AND " + request.getParameter("maxPrice") + ";";
```

Comment: You should really show us your Java code.  Your question is a bit unbounded without it.

Comment: I assume your query is a String that you are using in a `PreparedStatement`. If so you can just build your query based on the optional parameters you are receiving from the frontend

Comment: Java code: String


query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title LIKE '%" 
       + request.getParameter("title") + "%' OR Author LIKE '%"
       + request.getParameter("author") + "%' OR Price BETWEEN "
       + request.getParameter("minPrice") + " AND " + request.getParameter("maxPrice") + ";";

Comment: Kash next time add that code on the question.

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a validation for this, so you say in Code that the price range has to be not null and/or 0 otherwise show a message on screen and don't succeed. There are also other ways to do this , to restrict when no input is there, like PrimeFaces validation. Or you just define default values if the input is equals null. Just 3 of thousands of solutions. For future also give some information about what are you using and how your code look's like, so we can give a exact answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE (Title LIKE '%title%' or title IS NULL)
   OR (Author LIKE '%author%' or author IS NULL)
   OR (Price BETWEEN minPrice AND maxPrice or minPrice IS NULL or maxPrice IS NULL);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work from a Java prepared statement (I'm also skeptical of my own answer).  Maybe the OP can give us feedback.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP isnt using prepared statement :(

Comment: You were right about the OP not using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not currently using a prepared statement.  The best thing to do here really might be to have separate prepared statements which you use, depending on which inputs are defined and which are not defined.

You *might* be able to get away with a single statement, with the help of some clever placeholder binding logic.

```
String title = request.getParameter("title");
String author = request.getParameter("author")
String minPriceStr = request.getParameter("minPrice");
Integer minPrice = minPriceStr != null ? Integer.parseInt(minPriceStr) : null;
String maxPriceStr = request.getParameter("maxPrice");
Integer maxPrice = maxPriceStr != null ? Integer.parseInt(maxPriceStr) : null;

String sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title LIKE ? OR Author LIKE ? OR ";
sql += "Price BETWEEN ? AND ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, title != null ? "%" + title + "%" : "%%");
ps.setString(2, author != null ? "%" + author + "%" : "%%");
ps.setInt(3, minPrice != null ? minPrice : -1);
ps.setInt(4, maxPrice != null ? maxPrice : 10000000);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

// process result set
while (rs.next()) {
}
```

This answer uses a couple of tricks.  One is that for `null` titles or authors, we bind `%%` to the `LIKE` expressions.  This would mean that those expressions would always be true, and would effectively not even be there.  For the min and max price, we check if either be missing, and in that case replace with `-1` and `10000000`, respectively.  This assumes that you would never have a price less than 0, or a price greater than 10 million.

Comment: Why dont assing the default values for minPrice and maxPrice on the assignment?

Comment: We could also do that.  I'm tired of editing, and now I'll wait for feedback from the OP.  The best thing to do here would be to have separate statements, I think.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know java but this sql query will work

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE Title LIKE '%title%' 
   OR Author LIKE '%author%' 
   OR (minPrice is null or maxPrice is null or Price BETWEEN minPrice AND maxPrice);


query = 

"SELECT * 
             FROM books 
             WHERE Title LIKE '%" + request.getParameter("title") + "%' 
                OR Author LIKE '%" + request.getParameter("author") + "%' 
                OR (" + request.getParameter("minPrice") + " is null 
                     or " + request.getParameter("maxPrice") + " is null
                     or
                     Price BETWEEN " + request.getParameter("minPrice") + 
                          " AND " + request.getParameter("maxPrice") + ");";
```

Comment: You should use a prepared statement, and I doubt this would run, especially if the parameters could be `null`.